# ga:searchDestinationPage == ga:landingPagePath?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using the German UI of Google Analytics I stumbled upon two dimensions called "Zielseite" and one "Zielseite der Suche" [image: German UI]

So switching to English version brought up the following possible dimensions:
Landing Page and Search Destination Page -- no idea what the second "Zielseite" could be.

Using https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets I found the following API-names:

ga:landingPagePath 
UI Name: Landing Page
The first page in a user's session, or landing page.

ga:searchDestinationPage
UI Name: Destination Page
The page the user immediately visited after performing an internal search on your site. (Usually the search results page).

ga:searchAfterDestinationPage
UI Name: Search Destination Page
A page that the user visited after performing an internal search on your site.

So I started some analysis-queries:

```
 metric: ga:sessions
 dimensions: ga:landingPagePath,ga:searchDestinationPage,ga:searchUsed
```

All results had ga:landingPagePath==ga:seachDestinationPage (no matter if ga:searchUsed==Visits With Site Search or Visits Without Site Search)
That's not what I would expect. (155 with Search and 5237 without Search)

So the question is who this dimensions always have the same value and what which one does have the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Landing page path is the first page of a session coming from anywhere.

Search destination page is for INTERNAL search results. It is not a landing page -- it is the page you went to after you did a search ON the site itself (assumes that the site has a site search capability and that GA is configured to recognize internal search queries).

Sessions are counted ONLY on landing pages, and including search destination page in your query automatically restricts the query to visits site site search only (there is no (not set) value for that dimension - sessions without a value are excluded from the report). Try the query with Unique Pageviews, with and without the search destination page, and without the landing page, then compare.

Welcome to custom reporting in GA....

Comment: I've made the mistake with mixing session- and hit-based dimensions and metrics so often I thought I've learned my part. But it doesn't seem so... Thanks a lot.