# ga:landingPagePath without request

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm still struggling with ga:landingPagePath (see [ga:searchDestinationPage == ga:landingPagePath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080793/gasearchdestinationpage-galandingpagepath)).

Is there anyway to get a session with ga:landingPagePath==/pageA and ga:source==XY without a request to /pageA?utm_source=XY ?

I'm getting such results and I am sure there are no such requests!

Comment: Did you have a look at [PHP Google Analytics Package](https://github.com/OzanKurt/google-analytics) ?

Comment: @OzanKurt No, I'm not using PHP. The issue is independant from the programming language. I get these strange results using Google Web-Interface, Query explorer and by retrieving the data via R.

Comment: how does this question differ from the one you asked an hour ago?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080793/gasearchdestinationpage-galandingpagepath

Comment: @Dalmto The first question is about ga:searchDestinationPage == ga:landingPagePath. In other words: Is there a differnce between these to dimensions? If no, the question is, which one is obsolete. Because of the values I would say ga:searchDestinationPage is obsolete. Then this question here is still valid: How do I get these results without a relating request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ga:landingPagePath=~^/pageA$